# Boost interprocess lock_file does not work between two processes

Tags: c++, boost, locking, interprocess

I am trying to use boost file_lock to control two processes. I have process 1 obtaining a lock and then sleeping:

```
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/file_lock.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    std::string lock_path = "lockfile";
    std::ofstream stream(lock_path, std::ios::app);
    boost::interprocess::file_lock lock(lock_path.c_str());
    if (lock.try_lock())
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(30));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

while this process is sleeping, I will run a second process which tries to obtain the lock as well.

```
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/file_lock.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    boost::interprocess::file_lock lock("lockfile");
    if (lock.try_lock())
    {
        std::cout << "got here" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am expecting the cout statement on the second process not to print because the file is already locked by another process but it does print. What am I missing here? is file_lock not supposed to be used this way?

Comment: The programs work as expected for me (Linux), but opening the file _after_ having gotten the lock seems more reasonable

Comment: @Evg I tried what you said, it didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: What is your OS and are you sure you use the same lock file for both processes?

Comment: I am on Linux and yes I am using the same lock file for both processes.

Comment: @TedLyngmo so when you run the second process while the first one is sleeping, the cout doesn't print anything?

Comment: @hbnoory Exactly. The second program terminates directly without printing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best explanation I can think of is when your processes accidentally refer to different files. This might occur when

- the current working directories are not the same
- the processes run in isolated environments altogether (e.g. dockerized)
- the file has been deleted/recreated in the meantime (meaning the inode doesn't match, even though the filename does)

Here's a simplified program that can serve as both parties:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/06edf254505685ed)**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/file_lock.hpp>

namespace bip = boost::interprocess;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
static inline auto constexpr lock_path = "lockfile";

int main() {
    bip::file_lock lock(lock_path);
    if (lock.try_lock()) {
        std::ofstream stream(lock_path, std::ios::app);
        std::cout << "got lock" << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);
    }
    std::cout << "bye" << std::endl;
}
```

Local demo:

[image]